# How to remove gaps from a sequential number in oracle column

Tags: sql, oracle

Now the table structure and data are like below:

```
Name      record_number        Area
a         1                    CN
a         3                    DE
a         4                    FR
a         6                    DE
b         1                    DE
b         2                    CN
```

the primary key is (name, record_number)

the record_nubmer was generated by max(record_number) + 1, just assume that there are two records were deleted by record_number = 2/5 and name = 'a', so can anyone tell me how to remove record_nubmer gaps in the table above after deleting and the final results should be like this:

```
Name      record_number        Area
a         1                    CN
a         2                    DE
a         3                    FR
a         4                    DE
b         1                    DE
b         2                    CN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update the records with `delete` command, something like:

```
update my_table set record_number = record_number - 1
where name = :old.name and record_number > :old.record_number
```

I'm not sure whether you can create this trigger or not (and I can't access an Oracle deployment just now).

Try to create such an trigger (after delete each row), if not, update the application, so **after each delete**, the above query get executed.

Another solution is, execute following query:

```
select name, record_number, rank() over (partition by name order by record_number) new_record_number
  from my_table
```

now iterate over the result, and execute:

```
update my_table
   set record_number = :new_record_number
 where name = :name and
       record_number = :record_number
```

The whole thing can become an stored procedure, and then call it after each delete command.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @AmirPashazadeh 's [`rank()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions141.htm#i1269223), here's a one-line solution:

```sql
UPDATE my_table t3
  SET record_number=(SELECT
   t2.rank
   FROM my_table t1
   INNER JOIN (SELECT
    name,
    record_number,
    rank() over (partition by name ORDER BY record_number) rank
    FROM my_table) t2 ON (t1.name=t2.name AND t1.record_number=t2.record_number)
   WHERE t1.name=t3.name AND t1.record_number=t3.record_number);
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/82195/1)

Comment: thanks, but how can I get the result by Area field? I want the Area looked like this: CN DE DE FR

Comment: @user2575502 Do you mean `SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY area ASC`?